# NHibernate 2.1 Proxy Factory options - what are the differences and which to choose?

Tags: nhibernate

The NHibernate 2.1 download comes with 3 proxy factory classes that are available for use to enable Lazy Loading.

- Castle
- LinFu
- Spring

What are the differences between each of them, which one should I use in particular scenarios?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read more about them here :

http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/11/09/nh2-1-0-bytecode-providers.aspx

and

http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/2f78857456bde8d6

Basically at this point the main thing is : just pick one and be done :) .