# What's the relationship between Castle, LinFu and Spring with NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

I am a newbie to NHibernate and a bit confused about Castle, LinFu and Spring.

I understand that NHibernate helps in DDD and one can map entities to database using `xml` or Fluent NHibernate. But wondering how Castle, LinFu and Spring are associated to NHibernate.

Can anyone please shed some light or can point to any web link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I have used Castle and LinFu. I tended to use Castle if I was using other Castle components as well, such as Windsor. In fact Castle have an NHibernate facility as well which can be helpful. I used LinFu when I didn't use any other Castle components.

This blog post is slightly old but has some useful information on it:
http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/11/09/nh2-1-0-bytecode-providers.aspx

Check out the answer to these questions:

[What are the differences between LinFu.DynamicProxy and Castle.DynamicProxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406762/what-are-the-differences-between-linfu-dynamicproxy-and-castle-dynamicproxy)

[NHibernate proxy class, what should I choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122879/nhibernate-proxy-class-what-should-i-choose)

[NHibernate 2.1 Proxy Factory options - what are the differences and which to choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234704/nhibernate-2-1-proxy-factory-options-what-are-the-differences-and-which-to-choo)

Comment: Thanks for providing links, I found the article at http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/03/must-everything-be-virtual-with-nhibernate/, cleared doubt simply :-)

Answer (score 2):

Castle and the others are used by NH to perform dependency injection and type interception. NH is able to lazy-load data for example, because it creates proxies to your own types and intercepts calls to them. That way it can make DB calls and populate instances in a sort of automagical way.

All three of them do basically the same thing; it's up to you to decide which one you prefer.

Comment: NH doesn't use castle for dependency injection, it only uses castle proxy.

Comment: @jonnii Actually NH 2.1 supports injection, specifically POCO instantiation from a DI container. I've seen it done with the Castle microkernel. I don't know how widely used that is though.

Comment: I meant it doesn't use it internally to wire itself up.

Answer (score 1):

Although all seem comparable at first glance, I've personally avoided Linfu due to the [following issue](http://code.google.com/p/linfu/issues/detail?id=34) with S#arp Arhciture. This one bit me bad enough that I've been forever gun-shy. The Castle provider has never steered me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers pointed out, all these providers work.

For what it's worth, the *dynamic-update* mapping configuration (DynamicUpdate() in FluentNHibernate) seems to work only with Castle.

Comment: I use DynamicUpdate and LinFu and can confirm that they in fact work fine together.